# Android development folder issues

Tags: android, directory

I am trying to make an app that creates a folder **not** in an external directory a.k.a the sdcard but in the device's memory. I want to make a folder somewhere in the device where any user can have access to it and view its contents.

After search I wrote this piece of code but everytime I get the toast with the message false.

```
public void checkFiles(){
        File directory = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory()+File.separator+"myfolder");
        directory.mkdirs();
        File file=new File(directory,"myfile.txt");

        boolean success = true;

        success=file.exists();

        if(success==true)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

1) Is there anything wrong with my code?

2) If I manage to create a folder by code where will this be located? I mean in which directory of my device. To be clearer let's say for example  I want to make a folder near the documents folder of my device. (I cannot understand how to describe to you the parent folder.

3) Is there any other folder created when an application is installed? I mean something like program files of windows at an android device or I have to write code to do it?

**Edit:** I am trying to create a folder at the SD card.

Thx in Advance

Comment: Why a new folder on SD card is not an option?

Comment: By SD card you mean extra memory stick for example? Because you can't be sure that the device has an SD card. Or you mean the memory in the device?

Comment: I believe 99% of Android devices now have a built-in SD card so you can count on that. You get it by getExternalStorage() but it's a built-in one.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, do you have an idea how I can do that?

Comment: You get it by getExternalStorage() but it's a built-in one. On it there is a folder like 'external_sd' representing an external one if you specifically need the external one (if a device has both)

Comment: Wow, I think I had a blur image about that. I thought that with this function you get the external memory you can buy aftersale or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to make an app that creates a folder not in an external directory a.k.a the sdcard but in the device's memory.

I encourage you to read the documentation, as you may be confused about the definition of [external](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) and [internal](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) storage. External storage means "accessible by the user", it does not mean "an SD card".

> I am trying to create a folder at the SD card.

There is no SD card in most devices. External storage exists in nearly all devices, but it is not necessarily an SD card.

> Is there anything wrong with my code?

You do not have rights to write to the root directory of the device.

> I want to make a folder near the documents folder of my device

[Use `Enviroment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29), passing it `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS`.

> Is there any other folder created when an application is installed?

You can use `getExternalFilesDir()`, a method on any `Context` (such as an `Activity`). However, this is usually for files that you want to store on external storage but are not necessarily convenient for the user to find.

Comment: Use Enviroment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), passing it Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS. This will return the folder documents or its parent?

Comment: @Mario: What it returns is up to the device manufacturer. Generally, it will return the folder named `Documents`.